# Angular Material Design Flex Cards

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, material-design

I have this piece of code that is meant to be displaying cards fullwidth for mobile devices, 2 by for ipads/tablets and 3 by for desktops. it seems to be displaying the mobile correct but the rest reverts to 4 by

```
<div ng-controller="MerchantListCtrl" ng-cloak>
    <md-content class="md-padding" layout-xs="column" layout="row">
        <div flex-xs="100" flex-md="50" flex-gt-md="33" layout="column" ng-repeat="merchant in merchants |  filter: { featured: 'false' }" ng-show='merchants.length'>
            <md-card>
                <md-card-title>
                    <md-card-title-media>
                        <div class="md-media-lg card-media">
                            img
                        </div>
                    </md-card-title-media>
                </md-card-title>
                <md-card-title>
                    <md-card-title-text>
                        <span class="md-headline">{{merchant.name | limitTo:27}}<span ng-if="merchant.name.length > 27">&hellip;</span></span>
                        <span class="md-subhead">Large</span>
                    </md-card-title-text>
                </md-card-title>
            </md-card>
        </div>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: How about defining `flex-gt-xs='50'` rather than `flex-md='50'`

Comment: na that doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: using the code supplied below displays like the image above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example below. Added the `layout-wrap` directive to the the `md-content` tag (plus a few minor changes to improve style)

```js
angular
  .module('app', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('MerchantListCtrl', merchantListCtrl);

merchantListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function merchantListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.merchants = [{
    name: 'hello',
    featured: 'false'
  }, {
    name: 'world',
    featured: 'false'
  }, {
    name: 'sdfsdfdsfsd ds;fdsfsdffds sdfsdfdf sfdfsdf',
    featured: 'false'
  }, {
    name: 'hello',
    featured: 'false'
  }, {
    name: 'world',
    featured: 'false'
  }, {
    name: 'sdfsdfdsfsd ds;fdsfsdffds sdfsdfdf sfdfsdf',
    featured: 'false'
  }];
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MerchantListCtrl" ng-cloak>
  <md-content class="md-padding" layout-xs="column" layout-gt-xs="row" layout-wrap flex>
    <div flex-xs="100" layout-padding flex-gt-xs='50' flex-gt-md='33' layout="column" layout-align='center center' ng-repeat="merchant in merchants |  filter: { featured: 'false' }" ng-show='merchants.length'>
      <md-card flex='100' layout-fill>
        <md-card-title>
          <md-card-title-media>
            <div class="md-media-lg card-media">
              img
            </div>
          </md-card-title-media>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-title>
          <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">{{merchant.name | limitTo:27}}<span ng-if="merchant.name.length > 27">&hellip;</span></span>
            <span class="md-subhead">Large</span>
          </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</div>
```